# Как из Fragment обратиться к виджету Activity?

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, activity

Как в Fragment использовать метод  getActivity() ?

Данный код у меня вылетает java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo

```
 public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, null);

    Button button = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ((Button)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btnFind)).setText("Access from Fragment1"); 
        }
    });

    return v;
}


}
```

Activity.java

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);//java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo

 }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnFind"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="find">
    </Button>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment1"
        android:name="com.my_research_app.fragment_getactivity2.Fragment1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment1">
    </fragment>
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

}

fragment1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#77ff0000"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="frag1_text">
    </TextView>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="log">
    </Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: вы не можете получить во фрагменте `View` из активити таким способом и метод `getActivity()` здесь ни при чем/ Он возвращает текущий экземпляр класса активити, в котором находится фрагмент, а не его разметку

Comment: `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo` не говорит практически ни о чем. Покажите полный стек-трейс.

Comment: Если я изменяю наследования MainActivity c Acttivity  на  FragmentActivity то этот код работает хотя в исходниках android метода getActivity() нету ни в Activity ни в FragmentActivity  (  в исходниках  class FragmentActivity extends Activity ). getActivity() - определен в классе Fragmet -  так о почему ж тогда так происходит ?

Answer (score 2):

Не нужно добираться до виджета активити, она должна сделать это сама.

Сделайте в активити метод вроде

```
public void showSomething() {
    yourView.setText("hello");
}
```

А во фрагменте вызывайте этот метод:

```
 ((MainActivity)getActivity()).showSomething();
```

Comment: Error:(183, 35) error: incompatible types: FragmentActivity cannot be converted to MainActivity

Comment: Приводить нужно к классу той активити, в которой определен showSomething(), и которая использует этот фрагмент.